# How to count a number of duplicate entries in a group using a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a SQL table I have to columns: book_id and author_id.

Each is a unique set of values. If I `select *` from this table I might get some values for 
author id repeating for several different book ids like so:

```
 book_id    author_id
|    1627 | W3145     |
|    1628 | W3145     |
|    1629 | W3145     |
|    1630 | W3145     |
```

What I want to do is to select all author ids that repeat more than once using **exclusively** a subquery.

So whenever count of author_id > 1 for every such group of ids I could get this author id.

(Don't offer any suggestions or comments that do not contain a subquery please.)

Comment: Atleast show some effort before restricting the responses to the question

Comment: No, we're not going to do your homework assignments for you.

Comment: If this is a homework question, it's a bad homework question. Basically it tells you to do it in a way that is suboptimal. Subqueries are not exotic, there are plenty of good examples that will indeed require a subquery.

Comment: @SWeko Yes, it is a bad homework question. I myself, wouldn't do it this way, and yet I cannot come up with a solution that would satisfy this assignment in terms of subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select author_id
(Select count(book_id) from mytable group by author_id) as booksPerAuthor
from mytable
where booksPerAuthor > 1;

Comment: Er... this query actually makes no sense to me.

Comment: @spencer7593 Well it needs to be modified a little in order to work, but it was the first answer and gave a good idea what I should have done.

Answer (score 0):

#### Good way to do it :

```
SELECT
    author_id
    ,count(book_id)
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    count(book_id) > 1
GROUP BY
    author_id
```

#### Bad way to do it :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.author_id
FROM
    table_name t
WHERE
    (SELECT count(subT.book_id) from table_name subT where subT.author_id = t.author_id) > 1
```

I don't know how I wrote this :O